# Why do my UIImageviews get resized/dimmed when using UINavigation/UITabbar controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with a primary view that has a `UITabBarController` with 5 tabs. Each tab is a `UINavigationController`.

In interface builder, I'm customizing the background of each page by dragging a `UIImageView` and setting it fullscreen. The image I'm setting to the view is 640x960. I am setting it to be Aspect Fill.

However, what I've noticed is that it is not where I would expect it to be. When navigating between by tabs, the image seems to be shifted down from where it should be.

Also, when pushing a new view to the navigation controller, the background of this new view isn't offset in the same way as the tabbar one, and it is also slightly dimmed.

How can I set my `UIImageViews` on each page to be aspect correct and fill the screen 1:1? Also, how does one disable the dimming when pushing a view to the navigation controller?

Thanks for any tips, and apologies if this is covered in another thread, I couldn't find an answer searching the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the IB to setup your views, you should select navbar/tabbar options to reflect what will be on the actual page.  That should place your image correctly.  I would also recommend that you make both a low res and hi res version of your background images -- 320x480 and 640x960.  Of course, your size may need to be adjusted (reduced) for the navbar and/or tabbar which will leave less than 960 px of vertical height -- probably more like 920px if you are in portrait mode. Then you add @2x to the base name of the hi res version, this would account for older iPhone screens.

Once you have the image placed correctly, resizing should be unnecessary.  You can have the image automatically resize width and height using the little arrows on the layout page -- that's a bit hard to describe.  It can also be done in code -- if you still need that I can provide a sample.

Comment: You should go with this answer,if you are using nib then set the topbar as navigation bar,if you are using the navigation controller in your class.

Comment: Seems like this will be the best option. I'll give it a try and see if I can line things up properly. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck!  It's pretty easy once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Ideally, I was really hoping that my image would always maintain 1:1. i.e. not be offset by the navigation/tab bar, but I guess there's no way around that which is annoying. Just means I'll have to set up my views differently based on view type (pushed view vs. not, etc.). Thanks for replying :)

Comment: I think you might be able to extend the image underneath the navbar if you make it translucent, worth a try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set all **AutoresizingMask** in order to resize the UIImageView properly on each view. And to main aspect ratio u should use either AspectFill or AspectFit on the contentMode.

Comment: I'm currently using AspectFill as aspectFit would mess up the image because it seems to get resized due to navigation/tab bars